# Debugging sporadic 141 shell script errors

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, signals

While running a script on CI (Gitlab, Docker container running Alpine Linux), I am getting sporadic failures with signal 141 which seems to indicate a "SIGPIPE". But I do not understand which step is failing or what to do about debugging it.

```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash

  set -euxo pipefail
  set -a

  # ...
  git fetch --tags 

  RELEASE=$(git tag | grep -E "${BUILD_ENV}-release-(\d+)" | cut -d"-" -f3 | sort -nr | head -1)
  RELEASE=$(( RELEASE + 1 ))
```

The sporadic error seems to happen inside the pipe in the second to last line, the log I get is:

```
++ git tag
++ cut -d- -f3
++ sort -nr
++ grep -E 'prod-release-(\d+)'
++ head -1
+ RELEASE=323
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 141
```

How would I go about debugging this to figure out which line actually failed? It looks like it got the RELEASE variable populated successfully but then somehow still blew up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After `head -1` does its job, it exits regardless if `sort -nr` managed to write all the data to the pipe. If `sort` has something more to write and `head` is no more then `sort` will get `SIGPIPE`.

Nothing blows up. This is how pipes work. When you use `head` in a pipe you should not be surprised if the preceding command exits because of `SIGPIPE`.

---

Simple test with `yes` instead of `sort`:

```
$ set -o pipefail
$ yes | head -n 1
y
$ printf '%s\n' "$?" "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
141             <- overall exit status
141             <- from `yes'
0               <- from `head'
```

The exit status is `141` and it comes from `yes`.

This shows how to debug: by examining `${PIPESTATUS[@]}`.

---

The behavior is expected. Use a subshell instead of `yes` (or in your case instead of `sort`) to manipulate the exit status of this part of the pipe. Example:

```
$ set -o pipefail
$ (yes; true) | head -n 1
y
$ printf '%s\n' "$?" "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
0
0
0
```

More complex logic to suppress only `141`:

```
(yes; e="$?"; [ "$e" -eq 141 ] && exit 0; exit "$e") | head -n 1
```