# Getting first line of piped output sets exist status 141 which fails bash script with set -eo pipefail

Tags: bash, pipe, exit-status

I have a bash script that runs a command from which I want to get only the first line of output.

The obvious answer is `some_command | head -1`, right? Well, this works 99% of the time, but when the output was large enough it sometimes failed with exit code 141 since I have `set -eo pipefail` at the top. `awk '{ print; exit; }'` works for more cases, but still fails with large enough output. This simple script reproduces the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail
seq 1 100000 | awk '{ print; exit; }' | tee
echo "This is not printed"
```

This prints "1", but does not print "This is not printed". As I understand, awk (or head) exits before the input command (`seq` here) does, so the input command fails with SIGPIPE (141). I could of course work around it by setting `+e` just before the command in question and manually checking the exit code, but is there a better way?

I don't really want to remove the `-o pipefail` since I do want the script to fail if any of the commands in the path actually fail.

Comment: Also see this: [*Debugging sporadic 141 shell script errors*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/580117/108618).

Answer (score 1):

`sed -n 1p` works!

It appears to read all input, thus avoiding SIGPIPE. Even with `seq 1 10000000 | sed -n 1p` the delay is less than two seconds, and any real input would be way less than 10M lines.

Credit to Jonathan Leffler: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1429628/1536933 - that answer deserves all the upvotes!