# Has grep --quiet a bug with its exit status?

Tags: grep, gnu, sles

I have some SLES 12 SP5 machines with grep version 2.16 and on a single machine I'm heavily using scripts which contained the following `grep --quiet` condition:

```
# $pid_list contains the result of pstree and $script_pid equals $$
if echo "$pid_list" | grep -qF "($script_pid)"; then
  continue
fi
if echo "$pid_list" | grep -qF "($script_pid)"; then
  echo "Error: grep has a bug!"
  continue
fi
```

I doubled it, because by a chance of ~0.1% the first condition failed, while the second identical condition succeeded?!

After changing the condition as follows, it works flawlessly (Full code [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/741848/why-does-pgrep-return-randomly-a-wrong-pid)):

```
if echo "$pid_list" | grep -F "($script_pid)" >/dev/null; then
  continue
fi
```

Regarding the manual the `quiet` option should behave as I would expect it. It should even return true if an error happens:

> Exit immediately with zero status if any match is found, even if an error was detected

So I'm confused why it fails sometimes. RAM and filesystem of the machine is fine. The grep binary has the correct file hash, too.

I [searched for a commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=grep.git&a=search&h=HEAD&st=commit&s=-q), but the only one I found is [from 2001](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=grep.git;a=commit;h=66db7a353fdcc432905f1e8bc97a6a4cf8d06dff), which should be part of [2.16 as it is from 2014](https://savannah.gnu.org/news/?id=7800).

**Update1**

I tried to use a subshell as @kamil suggested, but it still fails (the "Race condition"-error is displayed sometimes):

```
if (echo "$pid_list"; true) | grep -qF "($script_pid)"; then
  continue
elif (echo "$pid_list"; true) | grep -qF "($script_pid)"; then
  echo "Error: Race condition!"
  continue
fi
```

This instead works:

```
if echo "$pid_list" | grep -qF "($script_pid)" || [[ $? -eq 141 ]]; then
  continue
fi
```

Comment: would you have a text file containing an example `pid_list` and a concrete example of `$script_pid`? I know it sounds like it's just as given, but we're looking at an "unlikely" bug, so being able to have a fully reproducible test case that we can a couple hundred times until you're sure it would have failed on your machine is necessary.

Comment: `continue` has no point outside of a loop, so please show the loop in question.

Comment: BTW: You don't need `echo` and `grep` for substring matching, the shell has built-in means, e.g. `case "$pid_list" in ; *"($script_pid)"*) do_something ;; esac`

Comment: Show a complete (but minimal) script that exhibits the issue, including the exact values of `$pid_list` and a `$script_pid`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Link to full code added to the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hypothesis: in the script you did `set -o pipefail` (if the shell interpreting the script is Bash; other shells may provide similar functionality). From `man 1 bash`:

> `pipefail`
> If set, the return value of a pipeline is the value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands in the  pipeline exit successfully.  This option is disabled by default.

When there is a match, `grep -q` exits early and returns `0`. Then `echo` [may or may not return `141`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/580117/108618). It depends on if `echo` manages to write everything to the pipe buffer before `grep` closes its end of the pipe. Even for the same input things may go one way or another, it's a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). If `141` happens then the return value of the pipe will be `141` because of `pipefail`.

Assuming you really used `set -o pipefail`, I say the behavior you observed is absolutely not a bug of `grep` nor the shell. The bug is in your script.

My answer under the linked question provides solutions. The simplest one for you is:

```
if (/bin/echo "$pid_list"; true) | grep -qF "($script_pid)"; then
```

or

```
if ((echo "$pid_list"); true) | grep -qF "($script_pid)"; then
```

Why `/bin/echo …` or `(echo …)` instead of `echo`? Because your `echo` is most likely a shell builtin and when "it" gets SIGPIPE then it's really the whole subshell that gets SIGPIPE and gets killed. We don't want the subshell that is supposed to execute `true` to be killed. See the beginning of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/580304/108618).

Check the whole script; other conditionals may be buggy in the same way.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm using `pipefail` and then it should be as you explained. Thank you!

Comment: It has been requested for shellcheck: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/issues/1109

Comment: @mgutt Replacing `echo ... | grep ...` with shell builtins for substring matching would avoid the pipe and the resulting issue related to `pipefail`.

Comment: @Bodo Thank you. I already read your above comment. But even if I use the binary operator `=~` instead, I still could face this problem with other pipes to `head` or `tail`.

Comment: @mgutt If your script depends on the exit code of the pipe in a similar way, then you might get the same problem. If you use `head` and/or `tail` in such a pipe, there are often ways to implement this in a different way. As these examples show, enabling `pipefail` for the whole script is *not* a good idea. See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#set_-euo_pipefail

Comment: @Kamil I tested `(echo "$pid_list"; true) | grep -qF "($script_pid)"`, but it still fails randomly. Instead `echo "$pid_list" | grep -qF "($script_pid)" || [[ $? -eq 141 ]]` works. I will update my question, if you want to see the full code block.

Comment: @mgutt OK, the answer now recognizes the problem. `echo` is a builtin and when "it" gets SIGPIPE, it's really the subshell that gets SIGPIPE and `true` is never executed.

Comment: if `errexit` is also enabled, you'll need `/bin/echo ... || true` instead of `/bin/echo ...; true`. There is a misguided recommendation to use `set -euo pipefail` floating around that many people seem to be following these days even though `errexit` and `pipefail` introduce more problems than they fix. Here `(set +o pipefail; echo ... | grep ...)` would probably be better. But best would be *not* to set `errexit` and `pipefail` globally and do proper error handling and set `pipefail` only when needed.

Comment: Yep, I disabled `pipefail` in the meantime. It's much easier to follow the principle "Does the most right pipe cmd do what I need?" instead of "Could there be a race condition anywhere in the pipe?".